# How I can get total sum of daily values of a column in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

There is an `orders` table with a `total` column that has more than 1000 records. How I can get the daily sum of `total` for each day. I mean for Monday, Thursday, Wednesday, .... there are many and different rows, and I want to show the sum of `total` of each day separately? in UI as:

```
saturday: 111211,
sunday: 211444,
Monday: 120012000,
Thursday: 1225121,
```

[image: Friday sales]

Comment: Normally you need to add the code you've tried, instead of letting us write it for you. But i see it's answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MySQL Query:**
SELECT DAYNAME(created_at) as day, SUM(total) as total FROM orders group by day

**Laravel Query Builder:**

```
DB::table('orders')
       ->selectRaw('DAYNAME(created_at) as day, SUM(total) as total')
       ->groupBy('day')
       ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ORM and this worked for me:

```
        $sales = Order::all()->groupBy(function ($date) {
            return $date->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
        })->map(function ($item) {
            return [
              "date" => item[0]->created_at,
              "total" => $item->sum('total'),
            ];
        });
```